# Setar o valor de uma TD usando uma função JS

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte função, que retorna um valor inteiro de uma consulta AJAX para meu banco de dados SQL Server.

```
function qtdItensUltimaCompra(){

        var url = 'AjaxQtdProdutoInsumo.jsp';
        var temp = document.getElementsByName("cdItemInsumo");
        var cd_unidade = document.getElementsByName("cdUnidade");
        var cdSetor = getElementsByName("cdSetor");
        var param = "&cdInsumo=" + temp + "&cd_unidade=" + cd_unidade + "&cdSetor=" + cdSetor;


        var qtdUltimaCompra = loadAjax(url,param);
        this.setAttribute('qtdUltimaCompra', texto);
}
```

E aqui a TD que esse valor precisa aparecer, no entanto não consegui através do `setAttribute` e nem do `document.qtdUltimaCompra.value(qtdUltimaCompra)`, alguma sugestão?

```html
<td align="center" width="15%" class="font-padrao"  id="tdQtdUltimaCompra">
<input type="hidden" name="qtdUltimaCompra" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Para colocar o valor na `<td>`:

```
document.getElementById('tdQtdUltimaCompra').innerHTML = qtdUltimaCompra
```

A tag `<td>` não tem um atributo de valor. O que você pode alterar é o conteúdo dela usando o `innerHTML`. Mas com isso você irá sumir com o `<input>` que aparentemente você tem dentro da sua `<td>`.

Caso não seja esse o caso e você queira continuar com esse `<input>` você deve tirar o atributo `hidden` que ele contem, adicionar um id como `id="txtQtdUltimaCompra"` por exemplo, para melhor manipulação, e utilizar o código abaixo para alterar seu valor:

```
document.getElementById('txtQtdUltimaCompra').value = qtdUltimaCompra
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Use innerHtml assim

```
function atualiza() {
 document.getElementById('tdQtdUltimaCompra').innerHTML="novo valor";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para inserir texto dentro de elemento que não seja um input, você deve usar o attributo innerText, da seguinte forma:

```
document.getElementById("qtdUltimaCompra").innerText = "Texto"
```